# Error Running Aurelia CLI in a Docker Container

Tags: dockerfile, aurelia

I'm trying to build a Docker container that has much of the tooling required for an Aurelia-based javascript project.  I have Docker community edition version 17.03.1-ce-mac5 (16048) and the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:yakkety

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qy \
  apt-utils \
  git \
  chromium-browser \
  xvfb \
  nodejs \
  npm

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
RUN npm install -g aurelia-cli

WORKDIR /workdir

EXPOSE 9000
```

I run the command `docker build -t maldrake/aurelia:v1 .` to build the container, followed by

```
docker run --rm -it -P -v `pwd`:/workdir maldrake/aurelia:v1 /bin/bash
```

to shell into the docker container.

At that point, when I run `au`, I expect to see the usual output of the Aurelia CLI tool when run with no arguments, a list of the available commands and their function.  Instead, I'm getting the following output:

```
root@11f3d17edfd5:/workdir# au
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resolve/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let core = require('./lib/core');
                                                          ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aurelia-cli/bin/aurelia-cli.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
root@11f3d17edfd5:/workdir#
```

The javascript error itself is easy enough to understand, and if I go look at that index.js file, it's true that there's no `'use strict'` at the top.  I can add it to that individual file, and that gets the Aurelia CLI running, far enough to create a new project, but then when I try to use other CLI commands, like `au test`, I run into the same error with other files that don't have `use strict` at the top. How should I be configuring my environment differently such that the CLI just works upon installation?

Node and npm versions are as follows:

```
root@11f3d17edfd5:/workdir# node -v
v4.2.6
root@11f3d17edfd5:/workdir# npm -v 
3.5.2
```

I've searched via Stack Overflow and, more generally, with Google and haven't found a description of the same problem.  That may well mean that I'm missing something facepalmingly obvious.

Comment: Read the docker best practices... You can install many packages in one RUN

Comment: Ah yes, thank you!  Probably evident I'm relatively new to using Docker...  I edited the Dockerfile accordingly, and updated the question post above.  It doesn't change the result I'm seeing, but it does optimize building the container.

Comment: Why not search docker hub for existing aurelia images? And why do you need a whole chromium browser in a container?

Answer (score 0):

I opened this question using Aurelia CLI version 0.27.0.  The issue was fixed in the just released version 0.28.0.

(edit) Well, partly fixed.  I still wasn't able to get a build command to execute without a similar error.  However, it seems that the underlying problem is an incompatibility with node 4.x.  So, changing the build to pull from the node PPA (version 6.10.x) solved the problem in its entirety:

```
FROM ubuntu:yakkety

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qy \
  apt-utils \
  chromium-browser \
  curl \
  git \
  xvfb

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -qy \
  nodejs

RUN npm install -g aurelia-cli

WORKDIR /workdir

EXPOSE 9000
```